# Short or Infinite puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Here's a small yet tricky puzzle :

> See, a taxi a poulp censoring is morbid sharp pain °

What is hidden behind the quoted sentence?

As the title mentions, the answer is wider than your imagination can think.

Comment: Well, I'm hesitating to add a tag that could make it obvious, this is why Iwent for this one. Let me ask the question then.

Comment: This is quite of an easy one to be honnest, I just wanted to share it cause I think he is funny, feel free to downvote if you want less content like this on puzzling SE! trying to improve everyday

Comment: Reminds me of, "What comes after green, red, brown, red, blue, --, yellow, pink?" [GCHQ Director's Christmas quiz, part 2](https://www.gchq.gov.uk/features/director-gchqs-christmas-puzzle-part-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> Pi !

because

> the number of letters in your sentence's words are 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 4 , and that's Pi (3.141592654) .. Granted, it's rouded a bit, as Pi is (3.14159265359 ...)

Comment: Well it was indeed faster than expected, the rounded is showed by the ° sign !

Comment: Yes, I though so .. and the "," is even at the right place, that's clever !

Answer (score 3):

Can I give a brief statement as answer?  Motto has clear circular character.

Comment: While this is clever, it doesn't do much to answer the question for anyone who doesn't already know the answer.